# Importing group members from facebook

Tags: facebook, api, import, export

If you own a group on facebook is there a way to extract your members data(name + email) via the facebook api? (this would be ideal)

Is there a way to do this through AOL Contacts(like when you can export your friends contact info) that works with Group Membership?

I saw a couple of simillar questions ... but no answers and not quite the same

Comment: I am looking exactly same. You found some solution?

Comment: the solution was to use the facebook API to mirror news to facebook :/ but that was sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to get the email addresses of every one in a group (for spam reasons). The closest you can get is the name, Facebook ID, and admin status by hitting the "/members" connection of the [Group object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) using the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Unfortunately, right now, you can only get up to 500 members of the group (again, for spam reasons). If you'd like, you can file a feature request in [Bugzilla](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net) explaining your use case and we can work on figuring out a way to expose the data you need if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: thanks jeff it was mostly for a class project with group management web interfaces,  but we never got to the point of implementing the feature it would have provided(heh namely import contacts...) but there probably would have been another better way to enable group communication through existing social network structures

Thanks again for the information though, if i do implement it in the future it should be sufficient to simply retrieve the names.